# Spring LdapContextSource ignores SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-ldap

Spring-Ldap 1.3.1

For testing spring-ldap with TLS I have created a CustomSSLSocketFactory-class accepting all certificates (I know about the security-issue with this).

Running a test however results in

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

With SSL-debug enabled, it is logged that the standard-truststore is considered:

```
trustStore is: [path_to_jre]\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
```

This is how the test is performed:

```
    LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();

    lcs.setBase("[base]");
    lcs.setUserDn("[userDn]");
    lcs.setPassword("[password]");
    lcs.setPooled(false);
    lcs.setUrl("ldaps://[server-address]:636");

    DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy strategy = new DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy();
    strategy.setShutdownTlsGracefully(true);
    strategy.setSslSocketFactory(new CustomSSLSocketFactory());  // <-- not considered at all
    strategy.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session){

            return true;
        }
    });

    lcs.setAuthenticationStrategy(strategy);
    lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
    lcs.getContext("[principal]", "[credential]");
```

For another test, I extended LdapContextSource like this:

```
public class ExtLdapContextSource extends LdapContextSource{

    public DirContext getContext(String principal, String credentials) {

        getAnonymousEnv().put("java.naming.security.protocol", "ssl");
        getAnonymousEnv().put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "[package].CustomSSLSocketFactory");
        return super.getContext(principal, credentials);
    }
}
```

The handshake than works as expected, but another error shows up:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090DF2, comment: TLS or SSL already in effect, data 0, v1db1
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.extendedOperation(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.extendedOperation(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.processContextAfterCreation(AbstractTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.java:133)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:109)
```

So the question is: How to setup spring-ldap correctly in order to make it use the provided SSLSocketFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually fails because of the ldaps-URL. If the truststore is setup accordingly, an exception shows that TLS/SSL cannot be established as it is already running (ldaps-URL and DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy therefore cannot be combined).

Also it seems to be directory-dependant whether or not StartTLS works on port 389.

Comment: For dummies like me, the solution is: switch the protocol ldaps -> ldap. Depending on your LDAP server setup, you probably also have to switch the port. If you're using the standard ports, switch port 636 -> 389.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error use `SimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy` instead of `DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy`